# Summarize a file system directory with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to output some cumulative information about a directory tree with PowerShell.

This is as far as I've got.

```
gci -r -ea Si `
| group { if ($_.PSIsContainer) {""} else {$_.Extension} } `
| select Name, Count, @{n="Measure"; e={$_.Group | measure Length -Sum -Average} }`
| sort Count -desc `
| ft Name, Count, @{n="SizeMB"; e={"{0:N1}" -f ($_.Measure.Sum / 1MB)}; a="right"} -Auto
```

This gives me:

```
Name            Count   SizeMB
----            -----   ------
.DOC            21660  6.988.6
.pdf            17323 11.893.1
                11958     24.0
.rtf             2112  4.808.1
.tif              736    359.3
.msg              490    318.8
.ppt              260    168.5
.zip              219  2.239.6
.xls              216     78.5
[...]
```

This is actually my first stab at doing something with PowerShell, so this might not be the nicest way to do it. Comments about approach and style are welcome.

- I don't like the duplication between `Select-Object` and `Format-Table`, can this be collapsed?
- I'd like to output a few more metrics, but I'm not sure how to do it properly:

  1. the maximum/average nesting depth per file type
  2. the maximum/average path length per file type
  3. the error count from `Get-ChildItem` (access denied/path too long) per file type
- These measurements could also be output as an "overall" section at the end, but columns would be nice.
- If possible I'd like to stay in one pipeline, unless there's a good reason not to.

---

EDIT: Here's my current version, calculating path lengths and nesting depths as well

```
gci -r -ea si `
| select `
    Length, `
    @{n="FileType"; e={ if ($_.PSIsContainer) {""} else {$_.Extension.ToLower()} }}, `
    @{n="PathLength"; e={$_.FullName.Length}}, `
    @{n="PathDepth"; e={$_.FullName.Split("\").Length - 1}} `
| group FileType `
| sort @{e="Count"; desc=$True}, FileType `
| select `
    Name, `
    Count, `
    @{n="Length"; e={$_.Group | measure Length -sum -average} }, `
    @{n="PathLength"; e={$_.Group | measure PathLength -max -average} }, `
    @{n="PathDepth"; e={$_.Group | measure PathDepth -max -average} } `
| ft `
    @{n="FileType"; e={$_.Name} }, `
    Count, `
    @{n="SumSizeMB"; e={"{0:N1}" -f ($_.Length.Sum / 1MB)}; a="right"}, `
    @{n="AvgSizeKB"; e={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Length.Average / 1MB)}; a="right"}, `
    @{n="MaxPathLength"; e={[int]$_.PathLength.Maximum}; a="right"}, `
    @{n="AvgPathLength"; e={[int]$_.PathLength.Average}; a="right"}, `
    @{n="MaxPathDepth"; e={[int]$_.PathDepth.Maximum}; a="right"}, `
    @{n="AvgPathDepth"; e={[int]$_.PathDepth.Average}; a="right"} `
    -auto
```

Comment: I've incorporate this as `Function Tomalak { ... }` in my `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`.

Comment: It's very nice of you to give it my name, but it might be much more sensible to call it `Get-DirectorySummary` or similar. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To collapse `Select-Object` and `Format-Table` try:

```
dir -r -ea si | group extension | sort count -desc | `
ft name, count, @{n="SizeMB";E={"{0:N1}" -f (($_.group | measure length -sum).sum / 1MB)}; a="right"} -auto
```

As for the other metrics (1 and 2), this should do the trick:

```
dir -r -ea si | group extension | sort count | `
ft name, count, @{n="SizeMB";E={"{0:N1}" -f (($_.group | measure length -sum).sum / 1MB)}; a="right"}, `
@{n="AVGPathLength";E={($_.group | select @{n="fullpathlength";e={$_.fullname.length}} | measure-object  -property fullpathlength -average).average  }}, `
@{n="MaxPathLength";E={($_.group | select @{n="fullpathlength";e={$_.fullname.length}} | measure-object  -property fullpathlength -maximum).maximum  }}, `
@{n="AVGNestingDepth";E={($_.group | select @{n="nestingdepth";e={$_.fullname.split("\").length -3}} | measure-object  -property nestingdepth -average).average  }}, `
@{n="MaxNestingDepth";E={($_.group | select @{n="nestingdepth";e={$_.fullname.split("\").length -3}} | measure-object  -property nestingdepth -maximum).maximum  }} -auto
```

I see no obvious way to accomplish metric 3.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Let's see if someone comes up with an answer to the other points.

Comment: Looking at your edit, I suppose splitting between `Select-Object` and `Format-Table` was not the worst idea. It bugs me that there is no way to output error metrics along with the other data, but thinking about it it seems logical in the context of a pipeline.

Comment: You're right. Splitting between `Select-Object` and `Format-Table` will improve legibilty and performance.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I've appended to my question the (semi-)final version that I'm using now. I assume to I'd have to put it into a ps1 script to output summarizing information (overall sizes, error count, etc). Should not be a problem.